# wheel lock nut identification

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

[image: wheel lock nut]I have purchased a used car, but it appears not to have a wheel lock key or any information in the manual and the tyres are in need of a change. I would like to know what make of bolt this is as i have never seen anything like this on previous cars that I have had, and any suggestions would be grateful as to which method is best to remove.
see pic

Comment: It might be something specific to this vehicle. Which vehicle is this?

Comment: its  a santa fe hyundai 2005

Comment: I took it to a car repair garage and a tyre centre both declined to do the job saying it would be too difficult to remove - [I am in FRANCE at this time, I know in the UK a garage would have no problem] I ask can it really be that difficult to remove them?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My model of car has a similar lock nut, they corrode, break or fail.

The most common solution for most drivers is to remove them - drilling or whatever and then fit ordinary nuts. The cars are old enough that the wheels do not tend to get stolen anymore...

Comment: and here. I think lengthy answers are hard to read some times. Do you answer to lock in users to improving the question or  easy questions deserve easy answers?

Answer (score 2):

Any tire repair shop has tools to deal with it they can easily take it out. Just go to some tire repair shop make them remove it and buy new lock nuts.

Comment: Not always the case, I was quoted a minimum of $200 to have mine removed by a tire/rim repair shop

Comment: It really depends